# Amazon ElastiCache Memcached/Redis: Map IP range to country

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, redis, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have a MySQL database that has an ip range (start and end, so two columns) and a country code (1 column). The database is used to look up the country based upon an ip address. It works but I want to speed it up more. An idea is to store the data on Amazon ElastiCache using e.g. Redis or Memcache. The problem I have is how would one go with this approach? Redis as well as Memcache uses key - values making it, in my opinion, difficult to store an IP range as well as the country code. What approach would you suggest for using ElastiCache Memcache or Redis?

The country range would be something like:

- 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.100 (Country A)
- 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.50 (Country B)
- 192.168.1.150 - 192.168.1.200 (Country A)

Now I get the IP address e.g. 192.168.1.160, I need to look this up as fast as possible and return in this case Country A.

Looking forward to your ideas.

Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just saw your question, even it is long ago that you asked, I have a solution proposal using Redis.

Let's first try modelling the problem with some basic numbers (instead of IPs) and see how it can be solved:

### Range to Country Lookup

```
   Lookup |   Range    |     Country
  --------|------------+------------------
          |     5      |  begin:Country A
      L1 >>>           |
          |     10     |  end:Country A
          |            |
      L2 >>>           |
          |            |
      L2.1>>>   15     |  begin:Country B
          |            |
          |     20     |  end:Country B
      L3 >>>           |
          |            |
```

#### Lookup `L1`:

Make a number lookup between `[6,10]` (*here inclusive range*). In that case result will be `end:Country A` => IP Address belongs to *Country A*. Why we start with `6` will be obvious in `L2`.

#### Lookup `L2`:

Lookup a number in range [11, 15] (*here inclusive range*) . Result will be `begin:Country B` =>

- `IF` Lookup `L2.1`
   
  => *Looked Up Number* points to the range start, i.e. `begin:Country B`
   
  => OK: `iff` IP belongs to *begin:Country B* value directly
- `ELSE` ERROR: IP does not belong to any known range

#### Lookup `L3`:

Result will be `Empty List or Set` => ERROR: IP does not belong to any known range

### Insertion is more tricky!

Inserting ranges must be taken care, because a newly inserted range might break an existing range. Here are the cases of insertion:

```
   Insert |   Range    |     Country
  --------|------------+------------------
          |     5      |  begin:Country A
          |            |
      I1 >>>    8,9    |  !!! Country C !!!
          |            |
          |     10     |  end:Country A
          |            |
          |            |
      I2 >>>    12,14  |  Country E
          |            |
          |            |
          |     15     |  begin:Country B
          |            |
      I3 >>>    17,21  |  !!! Country D !!!
          |            |
          |     20     |  end:Country B
          |            |
      I4 >>>    22,27  |  Country F
          |            |
```

#### Insertion `I1`:

Renders Addresses with IPs `6` and `7` (between `5` and `8`) to be invalid. => Effectively `Country A` range shrinks to single IP Address `10`.

#### Insertion `I2`:

OK, no range intersections

#### Insertion `I3`:

Renders begin of *Country B* invalid + renders begin of *Country D* (`17`..`20`) invalid

#### Insertion `I4`:

OK

**Note:** Probably you will need to introduce range splitting logic in some of the cases.

### Redis based solution

I'd propose to use Redis ZSET for that purpose. Here are the observations:

1. Every IPv4 address can be represented as a 32bit integer besides the dotted decimal string representation.
2. Redis ZSET guarantees uniqueness of the stored members by additionally ordering them with scores
3. We can search for ZSET members by using a score range, i.e. `ZRANGEBYSCORE` command.

If we use numeric IP as a ZSET score, we are done. Uniqueness of a country is enforced by prepending `begin:` and `end:` prefixes for particular range. In real life one country might have multiple IP address ranges, thus you will probably end up encoding the range number into the Country name, like `begin:r1:Country A` and `end:r1:Country A`. You could normalize this and introduce indirection. But to keep number of lookups low you'd want to denormalize it and have as much info as possible within single DB access. This is because introducing a new range is much less frequent than doing a lookup so increasing number of lookups will decrease performance.

```
   Lookup |   Score    |     Country
  --------|------------+------------------
          |     5      |  begin:Country A
      L1 >>>           |
          |     10     |  end:Country A
          |            |
      L2 >>>           |
          |            |
      L2.1>>>   15     |  begin:Country B
          |            |
          |     20     |  end:Country B
      L3 >>>           |
          |            |
```

#### What Redis commands to use

Here are just plain commands without your logic to check for error cases during insertions etc.

- **Adding a new range**

  ```
  > ZADD ip-to-country 3232235777 "begin:Country A" 3232235876 "end:Country A"
  ```

  **Note:** `3232235777` is IPv4 `192.168.1.1` represented as unsigned int, same applies to `192.168.1.100`.
- **Checking to which range a particular IP belongs**

  ```
  > ZRANGEBYSCORE ip-to-country 3232235778 +inf WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1
  ```

  **Note:** `3232235778` is IPv4 `192.168.1.2` represented as unsigned int and we make a lookup of one element (i.e. `LIMIT 0 1`) from `192.168.1.8` onwards (i.e. `+inf`).
- **Checking for `Lookup 2.1` looked up IP starts the new range**

  ```
   > ZSCORE ip-to-country "begin:Country A"
  ```

  **Note:** result will be `3232235777`

#### Complexity Analysis

**Space Complexity:** If in worst case we end up with every single IP representing start and end of a Range, we will need `O(2*N)` space, where N is `2^32`. But in real life this number will be much smaller. In some algorithm books you will see that `2^32` is considered a constant factor and thus will be reduced to `O(1)`.

**Runtime Complexity:** Redis states that `ZRANGEBYSCORE` is a `O(log(N)+M)` operation, where `M` is the number of elements in `LIMIT`, i.e. here only 1. If we have at most `2*2^32` scores in worst case than `log2(8billion)` is around `33` comparisons within Redis set implementation. But in reality I think there would not be more than 2 or 3 thousand ranges, which is around `11` comparisons. Redis states for a [`KEYS` command](https://redis.io/commands/KEYS):

> Redis running on an entry level laptop can scan a 1 million key database in 40 milliseconds.

All in all your lookup will be blazing fast!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a key per start/end range (e.g "80-255") and value of country code you could use either Memcached or Redis.

If you want less keys you could use a sorted set in Redis where the key is the start range, the score is the end range and value is country code (might save you on memory too as Redis is more efficient at storing this stuff).

Comment: I've updated the initial question with a practical example. Could you have a look? I like the memcached idea you proposed but I do not know if it is feasible in this case.